# Countifs with multiple ranges

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Hi,

In column A part number and column B type and the output required in column C.

I trying to do countifs here based on the part no (A) and type (B). In Column B considered the count of the lenth before "-" PB.

If any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your purpose

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A2,A2,B2:B2,B2&"*")`

It will cover both `BJ010` and `BJ010-PB`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am looking for duplication entry here for example the part number 1010 is repeated twice and type as well. Please don't considered the length of the type after "-PB". So now I we have duplicated line entry for the part number 1010. The expected out is "Not Ok" in column C.

Comment: column B(Type) different length of character not always the same. The logic here before "-PB" need to be considered the count with combination of column A. Something like this countifs(A2:A2,A2,B2:B2,B2)

Comment: @PETER - Does this solution serve your purpose?

Comment: Sorry for the delay response. Yes it's resolved my query.

Comment: Great, good to know this. Could you please accept this answer and give thumps up. It will help others to reuse the solution,

Comment: I will do. Where is the option showing. I can't find it in the same page. could you please guide me.

Comment: You can find instruction to Vote and Accept answer in this link -https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers